# Sorting an Array with a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to sort this array by price. If the item is on sale then by its onSalePrice and
if it is not sale then by its price. I have my current solution below but it doesn't work. Any thoughts??

The 'lowest-price' parameter is indicating toward the value in my option field. This parameter is definitely working okay. The issue is in the conditions that I am sorting with

```
const products = [
  {
    price: 28.99,
    onSalePrice: 22.99,
    onSale: "True",
  },
  {
    price: 26.99,
    onSalePrice: 22.99,
    onSale: "True",
  },
  {
    price: 24.99,
    onSale: "False",
  },
];
```

```
if (sort === "lowest-price") {
        if (products.onSale === "True") {
          tempProducts = products.slice().sort((a, b) => {
            return a.onSalePrice - b.onSalePrice;
          });
        } else if (products.onSale === "False") {
          tempProducts = products.slice().sort((a, b) => {
            return a.price - b.price;
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: Wouldn’t `const tempProducts = products.slice().sort((a, b) => a.onSalePrice - b.onSalePrice || a.price - b.price)` be easier? See [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](/q/6913512/4642212).

Comment: _it doesn't work_  What exactly isn't working? What is the output you get?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, that solution doesn't work because it merely sorts by the salePrice and doesn't check whether it is on sale or not

Comment: Hi Michel, the array is being sorted according to the price. Which is great. but the issue is, if an item is on sale it is not sorting it according to the price that is on sale so it is not being sorted correctly

Comment: @DanJamesEngineer _“it merely sorts by the salePrice”_ — No, that’s wrong. It sorts by `salePrice` first by subtracting one from the other. If the result is `0` or `NaN`, _then_ it sorts by `price`. The result is `NaN` if one of the `salePrice` property lookups reports `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const products = [
  {
    price: 28.99,
    onSalePrice: 22.99,
    onSale: "True",
  },
  {
    price: 26.99,
    onSalePrice: 22.99,
    onSale: "True",
  },
  {
    price: 24.99,
    onSale: "False",
  },
];

const getPrice = o => o.onSale==='True' ? o.onSalePrice : o.price;
let tempProducts = [...products].sort((a,b) => getPrice(a) - getPrice(b));

console.log(tempProducts);
```